# Clear Notification Center in IOS Swift at a fixed time each day even if application is in closed state or in background

Tags: ios, swift

We want some callback to be triggered everyday at a fixed time even if our application is closed. I am new to IOS Swift and have not much idea about API's available.

Comment: I have got it after a lot of search.Its not possible to trigger any event in IOS when your app is in closed state. What you can do is, you can store time in shared preferences when app is first time launched. After that whenever app is launched again you can take difference of current device time with that of one stored in shared preference , if its greater than or equal to 1 which means a day or more has elapsed, then you can clear notification center through this api call UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()